# need to run php script when form is submitted

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a form that needs to run a php script once the submit button is clicked, it needs to be ajax.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" id="entryform" name="entryform">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="JavaScript:xmlhttpPost('/web/ee_web/include/email-notification.php', 'entryform')" />
</form>
```

In this situation, using if(form posted) { get results and run script } is not an option, I need to run the script externally, that is why I need it to execute the email-notification.php at onclick

When I point my web browser to domain.com/include/email-notification.php - it runs perfectly.

Any help is appreciated.

This executes the script before you submit the form, now I need to wait to execute the script once the submit button is clicked, possible to do this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/include/email-notification.php",
    dataType: "script"
});
```

Comment: I guess you should point it to /include/email-notification.php in the form as well then?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering the same thing as well. Brad, is the '/web/ee_web' part supposed to be there?

Comment: /web/ee_web/ is the absolute path

Comment: Sorry if I don't get it, but why can't you just include `email-notification.php` in the target of the form?

Comment: using this w/ ExpressionEngine and am using a native EE form, in this situation I can not achieve it that way.

Comment: you're wrong about absolute path and you're wrong about impossibility of include as well.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel - changed path to '/include/email-notification.php', not sure what you are referring when you said impossibility

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you need something done when you submit the form, you can put whatever functionality is in `email-notification.php` inside the script which is target of the form, either by copying the code or including the file itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [$.ajax() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of the [jQuery javascript library](http://jquery.com/). It will make you life much much easier and is quite minimal as far as added size to your page (like 12kb or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using jquery. because of its flexibility and conveinience

If you want to send email notification and then only post the data then do as following:

create a separate page to handle your email notification like `email.php`

```
// fill in headers and prepare content
$result = mail(............................);
if($result) { return 1; } else { return 0; }
```

Then on your form

```
$('#mysubmitbutton').click(function() {
      $.post(
           'email.php',
           { emailadd: 'my@email.com', content: 'mycontent' }, //send parameters to email.php
           function(data) {
                //now check whether mail sending was successfull
                if(data==1) {
                     //message sending was successful so carry out further operation
                     //.................................
                }
                else { alert("Sorry, email notification was unsuccessfull"); }
           });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your "onclick" value:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="JavaScript:xmlhttpPost('/web/ee_web/include/email-notification.php', 'entryform'); return false" />
```

That's assuming that the "xmlhttpPost()" is something that actually works on its own.